# find href inside a H3

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the below code. I tried almost everything that I can find on this forum without success. I'm trying to get the value of the "a href" inside the H3 tag.

HTML

```
<div class="product" style="opacity: 1;">
   <a title="product" href="url-to-product.com">..................</a>
   <h3><a href="url-to-product.com">Blabla</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="product" style="opacity: 1;">
   <a title="product" href="other-url-to-product.com">..................</a>
   <h3><a href="other-url-to-product.com">Blabla</a></h3>
</div>
```

I need to get the value from the href inside the h3 tag and make it a variable to use in a getJSON function. I tried things like, closest, siblings and:

```
 $( ".opener" ).live("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data, status) {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

        **var url = $('.product h3 > a').attr('href')+'?format=json';**

        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
```

I always get an "undefined" error. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is `$(this)` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using:

```
$('h3 a').attr('href')
```

There are a many ways to solve this problem, it depends on your requirments.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
 $('.product').find('h3 > a').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting the h3-element and trying to get its 'href'-attribute. What you want to do is target the -element inside the -element and get its 'href'-attribute.

```
$(this).find("h3").children('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('.product h3 > a').attr('href')

$(".product").each(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).find('h3 > a').attr('href');
    alert ("Href is: "+a_href);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d76Re/2/)

Comment: this seems to work but the problem is I have multiple divs with class "product". Right now only the first product is loaded. I really need something with $(this). Any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated my question, it doesn't seems to work. Any more suggestions?

Comment: it's working.. see this http://jsfiddle.net/d76Re/4/ i think you might get stuck with other code